# Revert merge commit

Tags: git, github, merge

I am working with two branches: Feature1 and Feature2 (a branch derived from Feature1).
In the Feature1 branch, I merged changes from the develop branch, and subsequently, I merged Feature1 into Feature2 to incorporate all updates.
After completing these merges, I made several commits within the Feature2 branch.
Later, I returned to the Feature1 branch and recognized that I should not have merged the changes from the develop branch. I performed a git reset to revert to the previous state.
If I try to merge Feature1 back into Feature2, it says it's up to date.

How can I effectively remove all the commits associated with the merge in the Feature2 branch while retaining all the new changes?

Comment: You have to reset Feature2 to the state it had before you merged Feature1 into Feature2. Then you can cherry-pick the additional commits you made on Feature2 after the merge.

Comment: "git reset to revert" reset and revert are totally different. Which did you do? Please show the actual commands you gave git, along with its replies.